# How to design a database that needs to merge similar data from different sources?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'd like to scrape details of tennis matches from various websites and then combine them into a single database. Matches partially overlap across the websites and they contain different amounts of info.

As a simplified example of tables populated from scraping two websites:

`website_A` table:

| id_ | date | p1_name | p2_name | p1_serve_1_pct | p2_serve_1_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-Jan | Roger Federer | Novak Djokovic | 70 | 65 |
| 2 | 02-Jan | Rafael Nadal | Andy Murray | 58 | 57 |

`website_B` table:

| id_ | date | p1_name | p2_name | p1_serve_1_pct | p2_serve_1_pct | p1_serve_2_pct | p2_serve_2_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-Jan | Roger Federer | Novak Djokovic | 70 | 65 | 65 | 60 |
| 2 | 02-Jan | Rafael Nadal | Andy Murray | 68 | 67 | 59 | 58 |
| 3 | 03-Jan | Holgar Rune | Carlos Alcaraz | 70 | 67 | 57 | 58 |

In the above example the `website_B` table has an extra match and two additional fields.

I need to matches these matches together, dedupe them and then combine them into a structure that I can query. Most of the ETL articles I've read seem to seem to suggest merging the data and then creating a combined table:

| id_ | date | p1_name | p2_name | p1_serve_1_pct | p2_serve_1_pct | p1_serve_2_pct | p2_serve_2_pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-Jan | Roger Federer | Novak Djokovic | 70 | 65 | 65 | 60 |
| 2 | 02-Jan | Rafael Nadal | Andy Murray | 68 | 67 | 59 | 58 |
| 3 | 03-Jan | Holgar Rune | Carlos Alcaraz | 70 | 67 | 57 | 58 |

Note: In the above table the data in `p1_serve_1_pct` and `p2_serve_1_pct` are taken from `website_B` during the merge process.

Querying the combined table is simple however it bugs me that I'm duplicating lots of the data. Additionally I won't know which fields were populated from which data source if I ever wanted to track back.

I think there's an alternative option with a master table that references the other two tables:

| id_ | website_A_id | website_B_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 |  | 3 |

I would then write some logic into my queries to try and extract `p1_serve_1_pct` and `p2_serve_1_pct` from `website_B` first and only if they were blank then to extract from `website_A`.

This second option means I'm not duplicating data but my queries will be more complicated.

To my questions then...

1. Should I follow the first approach and just accept the data duplication? If yes, how would I create an audit trail back to the original data sources?
2. Would my second approach work? Are there are considerations to be aware of before going down this route?

It's probably worth mentioning that in real life there are tables for players and tournaments too. I anticipate the row and column counts to be:

- Matches: 1.5m, 200
- Players: 100k, 30
- Tournaments: 30k: 30

Also probably worth mentioning that I've specifically steered clear of going into detail about how the merging process is done. I can add details if needed but it's basically a lot of fuzzy matching as there aren't common fields across data sources.

Comment: Your second option is what's called an EAV (entity-attribute-value) model; you can search this site (and others) for the reasons why it's usually a bad idea. Overall, your question invites opinions, not objective answers.

Comment: Is the data on different servers?  (That is a problem.)  Or in different DATABASES?  (Simply use `db.tbl` syntax.)  Or what?

Comment: @mustaccio - thanks for responding. I've updated the question to be more specific. I've read up on EAV models but they don't exactly seem to fit my case. The examples I've read cover situations where entities can have different combinations of attributes. However, in my example each entity (a tennis match) needs to have all attributes (statistics) - they just need to be extracted from different tables where some attributes are duplicated.

Comment: @RickJames - the data is currently all in one database.

Comment: Are the desired attributes available in all the tables?  Please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for just 2 different tables.  And mockup a `CREATE` for the combined table.  Then we can give you specific code for that mockup.

Comment: Also, we need to know whether you are JOINing on ids or names.  And what  if the names are not quite the same?

Comment: @RickJames - the tables in my example don't exist - they're just simplified examples of what I think the actual tables will look like. I was looking for a conceptual answer rather than code. There are no joins in my first approach as all the data has been merged. In the second approach the joins are by `website_A_id` and `website_B_id` as per the table.

Comment: `JOINs` and `UNIONs` have different purposes.  Join to get more columns in a similar number of rows.  Union to get more rows with similar columns.

Comment: @RickJames - I think we're talking at cross purposes here. I'm not looking for advice on `JOINs` or `UNIONs` - I can handle these once I've got the right design. I'm looking for advice on the design specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loosely borrow concepts from data warehousing.

Firstly build staging tables that are largely 1-for-1 with each source. Populate these from your web scraping.

For the "proper" database, build dimension table players from all sources.

Also matches from all websites (date + 2 players).

Then your score % etc. become facts held against that match with the source.

If you have discrepancies in the facts from the various sources, then you need to decide what to do with them as you populate from staging.  If the facts concur, the source may become irrelevant, though of course you still have it in staging.

From there, you have a nice, easy data model.

```
PlayerDimension (id, name)

MatchDimension (id, player1id, player2id, date)

FirstServePercentFact( matchID, playerID, firstPercent)

SecondServePercentFact( matchID, playerID, secondPercent)

ShirtColourFact( matchID,playerID, colour)
```

If you wanted scores, you could extend the concept, either via set, or match:

```
SetScoreFact(matchID,playerID, set, score)
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) I have a few clarifications though! i) What do you mean by a "dimension" table? ii) When you say "build dimension table players from all sources" - this would mean creating a single player record in the "proper" database for every unique player from across the data sources? iii)When you say "Then your score % etc. become facts held against that match with the source" - does this mean you would leave the score %s in the source data and link the match table in the "proper" database to the data sources?

Comment: One additional Q... I note that you proposed new tables for each statistic (e.g. `FirstServePercentFact`) - was there a specific reason you didn't leave them within the match table as they are always recorded against a given match? I should mention that there are several dozen of these statistics so that's quite a few extra tables all with a very similar structure. In the past I have considered an EAV table similar to your approach - so a `StatFact` table with `matchID`, `playerID`,`stattypeID` and `statvalue` columns. However, most people here seem to advise against EAV tables...

Comment: i, ii) Yes - build a single "golden record" curated from all sources for players & matches.
iii) No - once you have cleansed & curated the facts, copy the data out of staging into the fact table.
Additional Q:  EAVs will trip you up.  Build more dimensions or facts as you need them.  Consider when you enhance what seems to be a simple bit of data , e.g. for a set, you might decide to add set duration.  EAV you've got nowhere to go.  It seems like a lot of typing but doing it like this is objectively a better model when you start to use and analyse your data.

Comment: Awesome thanks. A last follow up on the final question... one of the main queries I have to build needs to extract all stats by match by player in a flat file - one match per row. I have around 250 stats so that's 250 tables which means a query with 500 joins (1 per player per stat table). This is a necessary evil?

Comment: Yes in theory it would but use common sense.  The approach is sound, but a bit purist if taken literally.  The key concepts are around staging, curation and building clean data. If it makes sense for you you to accumulate stats onto a match/player/whatever table then of course do so. It kind of comes down to how complete your data is.  Do you have a handful of missing stats or up to 500?  Do you get all the data at the same time or does it accumulate over multiple sources/pulls?  You've got the foundation - you just need to adapt and apply to your situation. You've got this :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you have asked about mysql, but depending on a variety of things, you might actually want to use a NoSQL database for this. I know you say duplicating data bugs you, and I get it, but denormalization is SOP in the NoSQL world. I'm tempted to suggest mongo, even though these aren't really documents. Doesn't seem like the right job for Redis. Cassandra kinda seems like a good fit, but might be overkill. idk, I guess that is the answer to a different question, but figured I would provide a bit more detail in case you don't know anything about NoSQL dbs. Probably others can chime in on what they think would be a good fit.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/197850)